# Sort date in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date, tablesorter

I want to convert string to date in Javascript. I need to do it because I have an array and create table from that. After that I want to use [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com). But it sort it only like textfield. I trying to create new parser. I have string like:

```
"02 January 2010"
```

I need to create date type from that. Is it possible in Javascript? I tried

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(s);
```

But it doesnt work. How would I do that?

Comment: If using a library is an option, http://momentjs.com/ will save you endless headaches with dates in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a standard date format, you can create a date parser that doesn't need to reformat the date ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1223/))

```
$(function () {

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'ddMMMMyyyy',
        is: function() {
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s) {
            var date = new Date(s);
            return date instanceof Date && isFinite(date) ? date.getTime() : s;
        },
        type: 'numeric'
    });

    $('table').tablesorter({
        headers : {
            5: { sorter: 'ddMMMMyyyy' }
        }
    });

});
```